# How to enable code completion with a Node.js library in GLOBAL scope in Intellij?

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

I installed mongodb node library globally with npm and tried referencing that library in Intellij and in my project to get code completion.  I believe I set this up correctly (see screenshots) and yet Intellij still doesn't give me code completion and complains that the module is not installed.  What am I missing?

Note I don't want to install the module locally for this exercise, I want to use the global library, not a local one.

[image: my npm setup in intellij]

[image: my javascript setup in intellij]

[image: the error message in the editor]

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has offered some guidance I am going to answer my post since I have now fixed the "problem" or lack thereof.. Let me explain:

**The set up I described above does actually** work and gives auto completion with the 'mongo' library added in global scope and no library in local scope.  *I was getting incorrect auto complete behaviour in my case only because I did not 'require' the mongo library correctly in my code and so I was not getting auto complete for the methods I was expecting. I have fixed that now.*

I have to say however that this way of setting up JS/Node libraries in Intellij is quite confusing..  So if anyone lands on this page looking for advise about this topic then I hope this post brings some answers.

Another remark is that the **warning message in screenshot 3** is also normal.  This is because the "node_modules" folder is empty and so Intellij warns (correctly) that the code won't run.  The message still shows if you right click "exclude" the node_modules folder and add the library to it however your code WILL run and the folder won't get indexed by Intellij's pesky indexer.